# JS Wait till page Loads, Unless 5 seconds have passed then start timer (alter current .js)

Tags: javascript, timer

The below code is a timer for my site's ads. The way its setup now it waits for the page to load fully before starting the timer. What I would like to do is to Alter this slightly to only wait 5 seconds, if the page has not finished loading by then just go ahead and start the timer. I have no idea how to do this at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ptcevolution_surfer();
});

function showadbar(error) {
    $("#pgl").removeAttr("onload");
    if (error == '') {
        $(".adwait").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $("#surfbar").html('<div class="progressbar" id="progress"><div id="progressbar"></div></div>');
            $("#progressbar").link2progress(secs, function () {
                endprogress('');
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(".adwait").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $("#surfbar").html("<div class='errorbox'>" + error + "</div>");
            $(".errorbox").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
}
/*   End Surf Bar */

function endprogress(masterkey) {
    if (masterkey == '') {
        $("#surfbar").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $("#vnumbers").fadeIn('slow');
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#vnumbers").fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
            $("#surfbar").fadeIn('slow');
        });

    }
    $("#surfbar").html("Please wait...");
    var dataString = 'action=validate&t=' + adtk + '&masterkey=' + masterkey;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?view=surfer&",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg == 'ok') {
                $("#surfbar").html("<div class='successbox'>" + adcredited + "</div>");
                $(".successbox").fadeIn('slow');
                if (adtk == 'YWRtaW5hZHZlcnRpc2VtZW50') {
                    window.opener.hideAdminAdvertisement();
                } else {
                    window.opener.hideAdvertisement(adtk);
                }
                return false;
            } else {

                $("#surfbar").html("<div class='errorbox'>" + msg + "</div>");
                $(".errorbox").fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
    });
}

function ptcevolution_surfer() {
    if (top != self) {
        try {
            top.location = self.location;
        } catch (err) {
            self.location = '/FrameDenied.aspx';
        }
    }
    $("#surfbar").html("<div class='adwait'>" + adwait + "</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By your use of `$`, I'm going to assume jQuery

```
var __init = (function () {
        var initialised = 0; // set a flag, I've hidden this inside scope
        return function () { // initialisation function
            if (initialised) return; // do nothing if initialised
            initialised = 1; // set initialised flag
            ptcevolution_surfer(); // do whatever
        };
    }()); // self-invocation generates the function with scoped var

window.setTimeout(__init, 5e3); // 5 seconds
$(__init); // on page ready
```

Now what happens? The first time the function is fired, it prevents itself from being fired a second time, then starts off whatever you want done.

Comment: So i just replace all of what i posted with that what you posted?

Comment: No, only remove the following: `$(document).ready(function() {  
ptcevolution_surfer();
});`, the rest is all still required.

Comment: Ok so Replace "$(document).ready(function() { ptcevolution_surfer(); });" With all of what you posted there. Yes??

Comment: and this will Wait for the page to load but if it takes more than 5 Sec then it will start anyway. But if the page loads faster than 5 sec it will also start correct?

Comment: Try it and see.. That you're uncertain leads me to believe that before asking you didn't read through the code/comments in my post and you don't know what your own code is doing. If this is the case, you may want your original code writer to revise it for you.

Comment: The one that programed it is not around any more and the new owner does not know much about java. It doesn't seem to work, seems to still wait for the page to finish loading :\

Comment: So you didn't want _function_ `ptcevolution_surfer` to be called, but rather `showadbar`? As far as I can see, that isn't being invoked anywhere in the code you've posted, so I can't tell you what to change. It would be similar to what I did with `ptcevolution_surfer`, though, I imagine. The only named function that gets invoked in what you posted is `ptcevolution_surfer`, hence why I used that in my answer.

Comment: It should also be noted that the reason we wait for a page to have loaded is so that we know the nodes we want to modify exist. If you try to modify something before it exists, you'll get an error.

Comment: The Part that is loading the script is loaded in about a half a sec. Its a Page with a Iframe below the timer, the Iframe is what the start of the timer is wait for to finish. I just want it to wait 5 sec max because some pages take forever to load fully due to some error on the page, tuns of images or a slow loading page est...